# SQL Merge Two Select Queries with different column numbers while removing duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, inner-join, where-clause

Using SQL Server, I have two Select statements with Where clauses but keep getting duplicate results. My first query is:

```
  SELECT
    PricingContingencies.*,
    Terms.*,
    rscDescription  AS RateScheme,
    ptyAbbreviation AS PointTypeAbbreviation,
    FAKs.*,
    fat.*
  FROM ((((PricingContingencies
    INNER JOIN Terms ON pcoTerms = terID)
    INNER JOIN PointTypes ON pcoPointTypeFK = ptyID)
    LEFT JOIN RateSchemes ON pcoRateSchemeFK = rscID)
    LEFT JOIN FAKs ON fakPricingContingencyFK = pcoID)
    LEFT JOIN FuelAgreementTypes fat ON ftyID = pcoFuelAgreementTypeFK
  WHERE pcoPricingAgreementFK = 61523 and pcoID = 16490608
```

And returns two rows (which is correct).

My second query is very similar but has additional columns (the only difference is 'LEFT JOIN PalletPricing ON pprPricingContingenciesFK = pcoID)' instead of 'LEFT JOIN FAKs ON fakPricingContingencyFK = pcoID)':

```
SELECT
  PricingContingencies.*,
  Terms.*,
  rscDescription as RateScheme,
  ptyAbbreviation as PointTypeAbbreviation,
  PalletPricing.*,
  fat.*
FROM ((((PricingContingencies
  INNER JOIN Terms ON pcoTerms = terID)
  INNER JOIN PointTypes ON pcoPointTypeFK = ptyID)
  LEFT JOIN RateSchemes ON pcoRateSchemeFK = rscID)
  LEFT JOIN PalletPricing ON pprPricingContingenciesFK = pcoID)
  LEFT JOIN FuelAgreementTypes fat ON ftyID = pcoFuelAgreementTypeFK
WHERE pcoPricingAgreementFK = 61523 and pcoID = 16490608
```

And returns 6 rows (which is also correct).

How do I combine them so I get 8 rows total?  If I combine them using an INNER JOIN like:

```
SELECT
  FirstSet.*,
  SecondSet.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    PricingContingencies.*,
    Terms.*,
    rscDescription  AS RateScheme,
    ptyAbbreviation AS PointTypeAbbreviation,
    FAKs.*,
    fat.*
  FROM ((((PricingContingencies
    INNER JOIN Terms ON pcoTerms = terID)
    INNER JOIN PointTypes ON pcoPointTypeFK = ptyID)
    LEFT JOIN RateSchemes ON pcoRateSchemeFK = rscID)
    LEFT JOIN FAKs ON fakPricingContingencyFK = pcoID)
    LEFT JOIN FuelAgreementTypes fat ON ftyID = pcoFuelAgreementTypeFK
  WHERE pcoPricingAgreementFK = 61523 and pcoID = 16490608
) as FirstSet
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      PricingContingencies.*,
      Terms.*,
      rscDescription as RateScheme,
      ptyAbbreviation as PointTypeAbbreviation,
      PalletPricing.*,
      fat.*
    FROM ((((PricingContingencies
      INNER JOIN Terms ON pcoTerms = terID)
      INNER JOIN PointTypes ON pcoPointTypeFK = ptyID)
      LEFT JOIN RateSchemes ON pcoRateSchemeFK = rscID)
      LEFT JOIN PalletPricing ON pprPricingContingenciesFK = pcoID)
      LEFT JOIN FuelAgreementTypes fat ON ftyID = pcoFuelAgreementTypeFK
    WHERE pcoPricingAgreementFK = 61523 and pcoID = 16490608
    ) as SecondSet
ON FirstSet.pcoID = SecondSet.pcoID
ORDER BY FirstSet.pcoPriority DESC
```

I get 12 rows where the PalletPricing columns are duplicated and incorrect (the second results doubled [6 x 2]).  How do I combine them so I get correct 8 rows (2 + 6)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are basically looking for a UNION query. However, UNION (or its more inclusive sibling, UNION ALL) require the two queries to have exactly the same number of columns with approximately the same data types in each column. Unless PalletPricing and Faks have the same table layout, you will have to return fake data some of the time, and the column names from each of the two sources will be set to whatever column names you output from your top query.

Comment: Are they really duplicates? Likely, at least one column differs.

Comment: You are correct, one column is different.  How can I exclude that one different column so the entire row is not included in the query?

Answer (score 0):

For what you want `INNER JOIN` won't work.  Using a join like your current code is going to cram all the columns from each query into very wide rows.  You need `UNION` (not `UNION ALL`, as it's specifically intended to *not* check for dups).

As the comment you got mentions you have to have the same number of fields in each query, and they should contain equivalent data, otherwise your fields will have two different kinds of data depending on which query they came from.

When using `UNION` it's also a good idea to explicitly specify your fields, `.*` is a risky way to do it as you're betting that all the columns are in the same order in the tables in question.  So you could do:

```
SELECT
    rscDescription  AS RateScheme,
    ptyAbbreviation AS PointTypeAbbreviation,
    FROM ((((PricingContingencies
    INNER JOIN Terms ON pcoTerms = terID)
    INNER JOIN PointTypes ON pcoPointTypeFK = ptyID)
    LEFT JOIN RateSchemes ON pcoRateSchemeFK = rscID)
    LEFT JOIN FAKs ON fakPricingContingencyFK = pcoID)
    LEFT JOIN FuelAgreementTypes fat ON ftyID = pcoFuelAgreementTypeFK
  WHERE pcoPricingAgreementFK = 61523 and pcoID = 16490608
UNION
SELECT
      rscDescription as RateScheme,
      ptyAbbreviation as PointTypeAbbreviation,
    FROM ((((PricingContingencies
      INNER JOIN Terms ON pcoTerms = terID)
      INNER JOIN PointTypes ON pcoPointTypeFK = ptyID)
      LEFT JOIN RateSchemes ON pcoRateSchemeFK = rscID)
      LEFT JOIN PalletPricing ON pprPricingContingenciesFK = pcoID)
      LEFT JOIN FuelAgreementTypes fat ON ftyID = pcoFuelAgreementTypeFK
    WHERE pcoPricingAgreementFK = 61523 and pcoID = 16490608
```

Which is just an example for two of your fields that obviously match, you have to go column-by-column.

Comment: Unfortunately, the columns don't match. The FAK table has 6 columns and the PalletPricing table has 9 columns.  I tried to do a UNION putting in NULLs for the extra 3 columns in the first query but the result had the PalletPricing data INCORRECTLY in the FAK table's columns, since the first query has those column headers.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put "union all" instead of inner join.

```
 SELECT
    PricingContingencies.*,
    Terms.*,
    rscDescription  AS RateScheme,
    ptyAbbreviation AS PointTypeAbbreviation,
    FAKs.*,
    fat.*
  FROM ((((PricingContingencies
    INNER JOIN Terms ON pcoTerms = terID)
    INNER JOIN PointTypes ON pcoPointTypeFK = ptyID)
    LEFT JOIN RateSchemes ON pcoRateSchemeFK = rscID)
    LEFT JOIN FAKs ON fakPricingContingencyFK = pcoID)
    LEFT JOIN FuelAgreementTypes fat ON ftyID = pcoFuelAgreementTypeFK
  WHERE pcoPricingAgreementFK = 61523 and pcoID = 16490608
union all
    SELECT
      PricingContingencies.*,
      Terms.*,
      rscDescription as RateScheme,
      ptyAbbreviation as PointTypeAbbreviation,
      PalletPricing.*,
      fat.*
    FROM ((((PricingContingencies
      INNER JOIN Terms ON pcoTerms = terID)
      INNER JOIN PointTypes ON pcoPointTypeFK = ptyID)
      LEFT JOIN RateSchemes ON pcoRateSchemeFK = rscID)
      LEFT JOIN PalletPricing ON pprPricingContingenciesFK = pcoID)
      LEFT JOIN FuelAgreementTypes fat ON ftyID = pcoFuelAgreementTypeFK
    WHERE pcoPricingAgreementFK = 61523 and pcoID = 16490608
```